# JSON datetime field returned from REST Wcf method looks odd

Tags: wcf, rest

I am working on a small REST Wcf project. One of my WCF operation contracts (methods) has signature and decorating attributes is set as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetLatestOrder")]
OrderDto GetLatestOrder();
```

Upon testing that method using Fiddler, one of JSON date time fields is returned as follows:

```
"RequiredDate": "/Date(1383368400000-0500)/"
```

My question is that returned JSON date time format is OK, mormal? If not, how can I fix that issue?

Thank you.

P.S.:
I looked at another thread at [How to return custom datetime format in WCF REST Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199904/how-to-return-custom-datetime-format-in-wcf-rest-service) , but it seems nobody answers for that thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have come across one of the really unfortunate things about WCF's handling of json.

In short the format is correct compared to the JSON spec, that does not really address date serialization, and MS baked it in at a time where there were no real standards. The format is just the javascript standard serialization of a date sorrounded by slashes to make it easily parseable. So it is not wrong per se.

The problem is that this is a kind of suggested standard that noone else but MS adheres to, so it is really cumbersome to interact with clients written in any other format. (I have made my self very unpopular at both java and php guys for having made a service using the mentioned serialization format some years ago.)

The serialization is done by the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which has largely been superseded by among others [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) and [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text), both available at `nuget`. If you compare standard WCF to the latter to serializers, dates are represented as standard RFC dates. ([There is a relevant story and links here at Scott Hanselsmans blog.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx))

That was the problem. The solution is less obvious and takes some work. There is a starter here: [Implement Json.NET in WCF Message Formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679671/implement-json-net-in-wcf-message-formatter)

I have sometimes made use of returning a Stream from the WCF methods, since it will allow you to control the serialization entirely. But it makes the interface for your service less readable and it is somewhat a hack. (The idea with returning streams is really to allow very large results being written in chunks rather than allocating memory for the entire answer.)

Hanselman mentions WebAPI at the end. That is largely what I turn to these days. It has a proper defaulting when it comes to using the HTTP protocol. Makes proper JSON and XML serialization, is easier to extend and fits nicely into mvc. But it will never make it easily to integrate tcp or msmq as WCF does, and the configuration options are not endless albeit sensible.